# Using Windows on Mac keyboard without Delete key

Tags: keyboard, switching

I'm just curious - I guess lots of people with Mac hardware use Windows.

How do they manage to do so, given that <kbd>delete</kbd> key is missing on Mac keyboard and you have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to log in to Windows?

Are they all forced to use autologin (to bypass <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> pressing) or buy a PC keyboard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you press the Fn key, the backspace key (Mis-labeled "Delete") on a mac keyboard functions as the delete key.

Therefore, to log onto a windows install which requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, you would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace("Delete")</kbd>.

It's worth noting that this works even on the full wired keyboard, with a separate delete key.